# How to encode a NameValuePair list using Base64 class before sending it to PHP

Tags: php, android, encoding, base64

I have some data which I want to sent from android to a remote database server through php. I have made a list of NameValuePair type which I added as an entity of HttpPost method. Regarding this, I have used the following bunch of codes:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

In the above, params is a list(type NameValuePair). What i want, is to encode it using Base64 before setting it to httpPost object. How can I do that?

**N.B. I know the Base64 encoding technique for String value, but don't know the technique for a list (NameValuePair)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a StringEntity and apply the Base64 encoding to a String representation of your key/value pair

Comment: That should be pretty trivial. Just call the toString method on params to get the string and then Base64.encodeBase64(yourString.getBytes());

Comment: Okay, thanks again, just another query, do I have to serialize after encoding the params before sending it finally? if yes, how can I do that??